# Button click in userControl should change PictureBox image in Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form application where i have picturebox1 in Form. I have a user control and a button1 in that userControl. On click of that button i want to change the picturebox1 image in Form. Please check my code:

```
public partial class LoggedInForm : Form
{
    public LoggedInForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public PictureBox setImg
    {
        get { return pictureBox1; }
        set { pictureBox1 = value; }
    }
 }

public partial class AddUserGroup : UserControl
{
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoggedInForm x = new LoggedInForm();
        x.setImg.Image = NewProj.Properties.Resources.Logo;

    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: image does not change to the new one, on button click. i tried making the picturebox public. still does not work.

Comment: You are creating a new form by calling: LoggedInForm x = new LoggedInForm(); Then you change the picture, but you dont call .Show or ShowDialog.

Comment: Add `x.Show()` if you want to see the image.  Well, surely not what you want.  Raise an event instead so the form class can subscribe it and modify the image.  Most basic way to do so is to call base.OnClick so the user control's Click event fires.

Comment: can you provide some code or guide to change image on existing form. the control is present on that form.

Comment: [Pass click event of child control to the parent control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36130796/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I unterstood your question correctly.
But you can show an image in a `PictureBox` this way:

```
public partial class LoggedInForm : Form
{
    public LoggedInForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Shows the Bitmap on the PictureBox
        pictureBox1.Image = NewProj.Properties.Resources.Logo;
    }
}
```

The `PictureBox` have to be on the `LoggedInForm`.
Then you can assign an Image Object to it and it appears immediately on the window.

You have two partial classes and probably two forms and it seems that you want to update the first with the second window.
If you really want to run them simultaneously you can get more information
[on this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300887/run-two-winform-windows-simultaneously). It is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @joyD'souza updated my answer, but the important part of it is the second one.

Comment: You seem to be missing the UserControl part of the question.

Comment: @Oliver thanks for the reply, there is a user control here, and button click on that userControl should trigger the Image change on the Form.